# What is the best practice in Angular for creating reusable panels (ctrl & view tpl)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am new to angularjs, so maybe I am missing something, but I can't find a good way to create reusable views that I can instantiate (for lack of a better word) in a parent view.

My use case is a web app where I have a main view page that then has a number of sub-panels on the same page that display similar content based upon the same control and view template, but just with different configuration options.  (ex: small panels with summary of stackoverflow question but where each panel is configured to pull details for a different question id)

I have a JSFiddle working here: http://jsfiddle.net/abierbaum/Agbdz/

What I am looking for is feedback about two things:

- How to best go about passing initialization parameters to the sub-panel controllers?
- If there is a better way to do this.

Here is the core of the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<div ng-app="app">
 <div ng-init="names=['Jim','Spock','Jean Luc', 'Data', 'Riker']">
     <h1>Non-looping instances</h1>
     <br/><h1>First One</h1>
     <div ng-include="'panel.tpl.html'" 
          ng-init="name = 'Bob'"
     ></div>     

     <br/><h1>Second One</h1>
     <!-- Is this the best/only way to pass parameter to sub-panel? -->
     <div ng-include="'panel.tpl.html'" 
          ng-init="name = 'Pete'"
          ></div>     

     <h1>Looping Forms</h1>
     <!-- This is going to create a bunch of extra scopes: repeat & include -->
     <div ng-repeat="name in names">
         <div ng-include="'panel.tpl.html'"/>
     </div>     
 </div>

 <script type="text/ng-template" id="panel.tpl.html">
   <div class="panel" ng-controller='PanelCtrl as ctrl'>
       <br/>
     <input type='text' ng-model='ctrl.name' />
     <p>Current: {{ctrl.name}}</p>
       <button ng-click="ctrl.sayHi()">speak</button>
   </div>
 </script>

</div>
```

And the controller file looks like:

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('PanelCtrl', function($scope) {
   this.name = $scope.name || 'Jack';

    this.sayHi = function() {
        console.log('Hi, I am ' + this.name);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been working on an angular app for about two months now so I'm by no means an Angular expert, but after many nights of searching on Google, here's roughly how I do it. The key thing, and one of the greatest things in angular is scope, and the ability to isolate scope so that templates and the parent pages don't accidentally trample on each other.

Parent controller:

```
var myModule = angular.module('app', [])
.controller('PanelCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.dataPassDown = {
       dataItem: 'some variable',
       dataPackage: {name: 'name', age: '20'},
       someFunction: function(){ console.log('hello world');}
   }
});
```

Create your directive.

```
myModule.directive('reusableTemplate', function factory(){
    return {
        scope: {directiveData: '='}, // creates isolate scope and two way data binding
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            //your link function here
            if (directiveData.dataItem == 'some variable'){
                //do something based on variable passed in by parent.
            }
        },
        templateUrl: 'yourReuseableTemplateUrl.html'
    }
}
```

Now in your angluar page / html, call the directive:

```
       <div ng-reusable-template="" directive-data="dataPassDown"></div>
```

There is a great 1hr [youtube video on directives](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WqmeI5fZcho), highly recommended and worth the time, even gets into the fancy transclusion stuff. It makes the [angular directive documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) make sense.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I updated the jsfiddle based upon this and have a new one (http://jsfiddle.net/abierbaum/cVeSf/) that comes very close to working.  It allows passing settings in using attributes, but for some reason it is not working inside an ng-repeat.  Do you see anything that looks wrong?

Comment: @Allen Didn't see this till just now. You didn't need to have the other controller in there, the directive itself provides for link which can be used. The '@' option in setting means it will evaluate what is passed in first,  then us the result as the scope variable. This is 'one-way'. I've updated the fiddle, let me know if this is what you're looking for: [Click for updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cVeSf/10/)

Answer (score 0):

Create a directive with that template and use attributes as fields for settings.

Answer (score 0):

The approach is fine. Also in ng-init always try to pass a object rather than strings, integers etc, because child scope gets created and changes to the value are not reflected in the parent scope.